# bsearch return NULL but the element is in the array

Tags: c

```
#define u32 uint32_t
#define Narray 10

struct edge {
  u32 v1;
  u32 v2;
};
int struct_cmp_by_v1(const void *i, const void *j) {
  struct edge *a = (struct edge *)i;
  struct edge *b = (struct edge *)j;
  u32 x = a->v1;
  u32 y = b->v1;
  return x > y ? 1 : -1;
}
struct edge *array = malloc((sizeof(struct edge))*Narray);
struct edge *l = malloc(sizeof(struct edge));
struct edge *e = (struct edge *) bsearch(l, array, Narray, sizeof(struct edge), struct_cmp_by_v1);
```

The array is small with large numbers u32 but I only look for an element according to a field of the ,struct edge, that is v1 then the comparison is only made between v1.

The key used by bsearch is, struct edge *l, where l->v1 contains the element to be searched.

The ,array of struct edge, has element v1 to find but bserach does not find it and return NULL, I do not see the error that I'm committing

Note: The array contains only 10 elements to test but it can be a very large array with 25056012 elements, even more

Comment: Bad compare (no zero): try `return (x > y) - ( x < y);`

Comment: Your comparison function never returns 0, just -1 and +1. So it never tells `bsearch` it has found the item being sought.

Comment: Note: for a small array (N=10) linear search is probably optimal.

Comment: The arrangement is 10 only to test but it can actually be a very large array with 25056012 elements, even more

Comment: @wildplasser [Where to choose linear search over binary search](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22546024/995714), [At which n does binary search become faster than linear search on a modern CPU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275665/at-which-n-does-binary-search-become-faster-than-linear-search-on-a-modern-cpu)

Comment: I will read it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

`return x > y ? 1 : -1;` Never returns 0 (a match). Try `return (int)(x - y);` (just noted unsigned types so need to be aware of that - I've used a simple cast but there is likely a safer way)

Comment re: overflow is correct (but unlikely in normal usage), if on is a huge positive and the other is a huge negative then you're going to have problems.

A nice clear way to handle any size without overflow or sign issues:

```
if (x == y)
    return 0;
return x > y ? 1 : -1;
```

Comment: While subtraction works when the numbers are small, it risks overflow if the numbers are large.  It isn't a good way to write a comparator.

Comment: the comparator that I need must support large unsigned int numbers, in this case it must support an unsigned 32-bit integer

Comment: @IvanPereyra Key point is you don't have a "return 0 if equal" case. Fix that and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers, they helped me find the solution.
I still do not probe it for a large array.
Anyway, the comparison function is:

```
int struct_cmp_by_v2(const void *i, const void *j) {
  struct edge *a = (struct edge *)i;
  struct edge *b = (struct edge *)j;
  u32 x = a->v1;
  u32 y = b->v1;
  if (x == y)
    return 0;
  else {
    if (x > y)
      return 1;
    else
      return -1;
  }
}
```

Comment: `return (x > y) - (x < y);` will be much simpler and there's no overflow whatsoever

Comment: What you have there is likely to cause compiler warnings about the fn not returning a value since the returns are buried in elses. I'd refactor to `if (x != y) { ... } return 0;`

Comment: @John3136: It is easy to see each case in the above returns a value. Can you cite any particular compiler and version which produces a warning for the code shown?

Comment: @EricPostpischil - Easy for a person to see but not necessarily a compiler. You'll note I said warnings - not errors.

Comment: @John3136: This is easy for a compiler to see. In analyzing the source, compilers construct graphs (or other structures) of potential control flow. In this case, where every branch contains a return, the graph shows no control flow reaching the end of the function.

Comment: @EricPostpischil We'll have to agree to disagree. I'm not going to try it on all the ancient compilers I currently have to use. Pretty sure one of the older solaris C compilers flags this. Perhaps I'll flip my comment. Perhaps the compiler can tell, but in a 1000+ line function (the joys of legacy code) the maintainer will have a lot of work to check ;-)